# Pandas dataframe combine rows representing the same entity

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have data that contains several rows for each employee. Each row contains one attribute and its value. For example:

| Worker ID | Last Name | First Name | Metric Name | Metric Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hanson | Scott | Attendance | 98 |
| 1 | Hanson | Scott | On time | 35 |
| 2 | Avery | Kara | Attendance | 95 |
| 2 | Avery | Kara | On time | 57 |

I would like to combine rows based on worker id, taking metrics to their own columns like so:

| Worker ID | Last Name | First Name | Attendance | On time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hanson | Scott | 98 | 35 |
| 2 | Avery | Kara | 95 | 57 |

I can do `worker_data.pivot_table(values='Metric Value', index='Worker ID', columns=['Metric Name'])`, but that does not give me the first and last names as columns. What is the best Pandas way to merge these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution change `index` parameter by list and for avoid `MultiIndex` remove `[]` from column parameter:

```
df = (worker_data.pivot_table(index=['Worker ID','Last Name','First Name'], 
                              columns='Metric Name',
                              values='Metric Value')
                 .reset_index()
                 .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```